# Does the Kafka Consumer configuration option "auto.offset.reset" include the last event on the topic when set to "latest"?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka consumers have a configuration option `auto.offset.reset`.

It can be set to

- `earliest`
- `latest`
- `none`

This configuration is used to initialize a consumer group offset in the case where no previously committed offset is available.

This can happen for several reasons:

- The broker has never seen the `group.id` before. A new consumer group has connected, or a consumer group previously connected with the same `group.id` but did not commit
- The broker has expired old commit offsets. The garbage collection of old offsets is usually set to 7 days by default
- The part of the log containing messages with the committed offsets has been garbage collected itself, because the log retention time or size (GB) has been exceeded

If `auto.offset.reset` is set to `none` an exception is thrown if no previous offset exists. If it is set to `earliest` then **all events in a topic become available to read**.

- What happens in the case of `latest`? The offset will be set to the "end" of a topic, but what does this mean? Is it "at the end" with a single record available to consume, or "beyond the end" meaning there will be no records to consume until some other process produces new records with new offsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> no records to consume until some other process produces new records with new offsets?

It means this. You need to seek backwards to consume any existing offsets

Answer (score 0):

The `latest` setting value for the `auto.offset.reset` means that the consumer will start reading from the “end” of the log and that means once the configuration is set , the consumer will ignore any messages that were sent to the topic before it started and will only consume new messages that arrive after it has begun listening to the topic.